# What is the current status of Volley in 2015

Tags: android, android-volley

The most recent commits on Volley https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley are "4 weeks" ago.
It was very active in 2013.

Google put Volley in the documentation http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

**Is it wise to use Volley for a new project ?**

I see that Google I/O 2014 Android App is not even using Volley . But it uses Glide for the image loading
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/build.gradle

If Google developers are using Glide ( former bu.mp acqui-hired by Google ), then one would wonder shouldn't we use Glide too ( or put any library )

PS : I am using with Retrofit and Picasso. On Picasso, I am experiencing some OutOfMemory exceptions and image not loading issues

**Will Volley continue to be supported ?**

Comment: Are you having a problem with Retrofit and Picasso? IOW, why change at all?

Comment: On Picasso , we have loading image issues